# Do vegetable saturated fats increase cholesterol?

Tags: health, fats, cholesterol

Many studies have investigated the relation between the intake of saturated fats and the increase of cholesterol. Saturated fats are usually found in animal products, such as meat and dairy. We can speculate that saturated fats are not all the same, and there *might* a difference between animal and vegetable source of saturated fats. Are there any studies that can answer this question? Do vegetable saturated fats increase cholesterol?

Answer (score 7):

**I will try to answer your question based on the [types of saturated fats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_fat#Fat_profiles) that some vegetable sources contain as compared to animal sources.**

The presumably two biggest sources of saturated fats in vegan diet are **coconut products** (notably coconut oil) and **palm oil**. Other sources can be various **nuts, non-exotic oils, cacao** etc. but these contain smaller amounts than the two previously mentioned oils.

Saturated fats in **coconut oil** are, proportionally, like this:

```
Lauric acid  Myristic acid  Palmitic acid  Stearic acid
        47%            18%             9%            3%
```

For **palm oil**, the saturated fats content looks like this:

```
Lauric acid  Myristic acid  Palmitic acid  Stearic acid
        48%             1%            44%            5%
```

As you can see, both are rather high in **Lauric acid**, with palm oil being high in **Palmitic acid** as well. While Lauric acid [has been found to have a positive impact on HDL](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/77/5/1146.full?ijkey=846a72387ebc0d82545acd5442a0c3a9e9fc3566) (the *good* cholesterol) levels, the Palmitic acid is not so great and its consumption has been **connected to rise of LDL** (the *bad* cholesterol) and subsequential onset of [corronary diseases](http://www.freezepage.com/1348239076FHWAJDADVT).

For comparison, most of the **animal products** have just marginal Laruic or Myristic acid contents and rather **high Palmitic and Stearic acid contents**.

```
Food         Lauric acid  Myristic acid  Palmitic acid  Stearic acid
Butter                3%            11%            29%           13%
Ground beef           0%             4%            26%           15%
Salmon                0%             1%            29%            3%
Egg yolks             0%           0.3%            27%           10%
```

While Stearic acid does not have such a bad effect on our body, these product are all high in exactly the Palmitic acid which causes the most trouble.

**TL;DR** (which turned out to be too long to read, ironically):

To answer your question - yes, **vegetable saturated fats do increase cholesterol**, just like any other fats. The important thing to keep in mind is that **there is good and bad cholesterol** and different types of saturated fats increase different types of cholesterol.

While **palm oil** is pretty high in not so good Palmitic acid, it also contains high values of Lauric acid which somehow negates these effects (presumably).

As for the **coconut oil**, while it has high content of saturated fats, **majority of these are the good kind**, with relatively small amounts of Palmitic acid and 18% proportion to the total fat conent of Myristic acid which is, along with Palmitic acid, linked to the increased risk for cardiovascular diseases.

When it comes to other **vegetable sources of saturated fats**, these all have just small amounts of saturated fats in their total fat content and are henceforth less harmful than animal products which contain more of these.

### Therefore **it can be argued that in fact, all of the vegetable sources of saturated fats are less harmful than their animal counterparts**.

**EDIT:** As requested by the OP in the comments, I will explain the sources for these claims in a little bit more detail:

To cite from the [previously included source](http://www.freezepage.com/1348239076FHWAJDADVT) at page 82 (the hihglight is mine):

> The relationship between dietary fats and CVD, especially coronary
> heart disease, has been extensively investigated, with strong and
> consistent associations emerging from a wide body of evidence accrued
> from **animal experiments**, as well as **observational studies, clinical
> trials** and **metabolic studies** conducted in diverse human populations
> (2).
>
> **Saturated fatty acids raise total and low-density lipoprotein
> (LDL) cholesterol**, but individual fatty acids within this group, have
> different effects (3--5). Myristic and **palmitic acids have the
> greatest effect** and are abundant in diets rich in dairy products and
> meat.

I would also like to point out the **Table 10** in the [same source](http://www.freezepage.com/1348239076FHWAJDADVT) at p.89 which shows factors that decrease or increase risk of cardiovascular diseases along with the probability (based on the strength of evidence) for these factors. The **palmitic and myristic acid** are on the top of the table for **increasing the risk** with the **strength of evidence** set as **convincing**.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, however your answer is kind of weak: it's not really clear which source you used to say that palmitic acid increases LDL cholesterol. it should be pointed out which kind of study was done (cohort study with dietary recall, or clinical trial, etc.) and which where the results. in this way the causal relation between the consumption of vegetable saturated fats and increase of total and LDL cholesterol should be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited my answer to specifically address your concerns. Is there anything else you would like me to specify?

Comment: Upvote for the effort. Still it doesn't completely answer my question. I know, it's a matter of details, but I'll try to be as clear as possible. You decompose sat-fats into fatty acids, and say myristic and palmitic acids make cholesterol increase. However in this experiment they were still from animal sources. We can speculate they have different impact if they come from animal or vegetable source, for reasons that we might not know (still). It would be perfect to have a trial where 2 groups are fed with vegan diets, with two different levels of fats, and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Well I am afraid there is no such study for the time being and I doubt there ever will be. Your assumption that two identical substances have different impact based on whether they are from animal or vegetable source seems rather surprising to me. Do you have some reason to believe this? If there are no structural differences between the two, it is very unlikely they will have different metabolic destiny in our bodies. And as for there being things that we might still not know, well, that is hard to argue about - yes, there might, but unless we know for sure, let's just work with what we have

Comment: If such a study hasn't been done yet, then the correct answer is "we still don't know". As for the substances (with "no structural differences") that might have different effect, we have reasons to *suspect* that this *might* happen. For example, there are several studies where supplementation with vitamins didn't sort out the expected results, ALTOUGH natural and artificial vitamins have the same molecular structure.

Comment: As for your first argument, if that was true, it would have a debilitating effect on almost everything we kow about the world. By ways of eg. induction, we can assume things to be true even if we do not explore every little detail about them. As for the several studies about the vitamins with the *same* structure, could you point me to at least one? I know there have been studies regarding vitamin E from natural and artificial sources that have shown differences, but in these those were two different *enantiomers* of the same molecule. I would be interested to hear about other studies.

Comment: Yes, most of them are about vit. E, but also other nutrients: in "Messina, et al (2001). Reductionism and the narrowing nutrition perspective: time for reevaluation and emphasis on food synergy": see Notes 5 to 7. You might also be pleased to read "Fortmann et al. (2013). Vitamin and mineral supplements inthe primary prevention of cardiovascular disease and cancer: An updated systematic evidence review for the U.S. Preventive Services Task Force" and - perhaps - "Lichtenstein AH, Russell RM. Essential nutrients: food or supplements? Where should the emphasis be? JAMA. 2005"

Comment: I had a quick look (+-30 min) at the references you pointed me to and I have not seen a single mention of comparison of any vitamin nor any other nutrient in its *natural* and *artificial* form. Most of them are concerned with testing vitamins against placebo. The others are not concerned with testing vitamins at all and just talk about food synergy, which, although an interesting concept, has nothing to do with your assumption that **two structurally identical molecules have different impact because of where they come from**. I cannot really reply much more based on this.